# How can I calculate living expense for a Schengen visa application?

Tags: family, schengen, sweden, poland

`P` is a PhD student on a monthly scholarship at a university in Poland. He lives in Poland and has a 3-year temporary residence permit. Now, he wants to bring his wife and 9-year-old only child to Poland.

The catch is that his country doesn't have a Polish embassy. So his wife and child have to apply for a 3-month Schengen visa in the Swedish embassy located in his home country.

In that case, how much money should `P` show at minimum in his bank account as the living expenses for his wife and child (when his wife and child apply for their Schengen visa)?

Comment: Whether the amount is fixed or based on individual circumstances, you should expect it to be determined with reference to Polish regulations.  If Sweden is making the decision instead of forwarding the application to Poland, it will have received instructions from Poland to this effect as part of the agreement to process visas.  Everybody recognizes that the cost of living is different in different places and the point of these representation agreements is to make things easier for the visa issuing countries, not to impose irrational requirements on visa applicants.

Comment: Where are your wife and child living? They have to apply where they are living, whether or not that is the country of P's citizenship. Also do you really want them to come only for a 3 month visit, or to join you while you study?

Comment: [Annex 25](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2023-09/handbook-annex_25_EN.pdf) may be relevant

Answer (score 1):

The amount of money you should put as expenses is the amount of money that it will actually cost you/them to stay with you for three months. Work out the cost of travel, food, and anything else you need to spend for them to come to you. Hopefully you have worked this out before you decided they should visit you.

The most important question is whether they can share accommodation with you. Is your student accommodation big enough for a family of three? Are you allowed to have them stay with you? If it's university or rented accommodation you may need to include an official letter stating that they are allowed to stay with you. Otherwise they may need to stay in a hotel.

Once you have worked out the cost, you will need to show that you (or her) have enough money to make that expense a sensible thing to do. That's not just having that amount in an account, but that you can afford it. If you had that much in an account but it meant you had no money left for your studies they would not believe the visit was legitimate.